# Xamarin with .Net Framework

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have started to learn Xamarin. From what I read, .Net Standard allows a developer to use code from another .Net platform into Xamarin.

The examples that I read only talk about MVC or .Net Core. The documentation says that the developer can use .Net Standard with .Net Framework 4.6.1. Visual Studio 2019 has the option to include an Asp.Net Core Web API Project as part of a mobile backend.

Is there there a .Net Framework option available?

I have a lot of .Net Framework Pages that I would like to include into Xamarin.

Do I need to rewrite all the code or is there a conversion process I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Standard defines the common subset of libraries and features that are shared by both .NET Core and .NET Framework. If your existing code is using .NET Framework, it's possible that most or all of the framework features that the code relies on are supported by .NET Standard. If so, it will be easy to port the code to a .NET Standard assembly, which can be used by Xamarin. The difficulty of the port will depend on how many .NET Framework-specific features you're using.

Microsoft provides a tool to analyze how compatible your code is, you can find details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer)